# How do I write a function with extend functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to realize a function e.g. `MyFn()` with some features as follows:
**1. MyFn('Id')**  > It must be result the value of document.getElementById('Id');
**2. MyFn('Id').MyMethode();**  > It must be result the performing of a function.
Below this is realized by means of "Object.prototype" as follows:

```
Object.prototype.MyFn =function(param1){ return document.getElementById(param1); };
alert( MyFn('mydiv1') );
MyFn('mydiv1').posi = function() { alert("Hello, I'm the function posi!"); };
MyFn('mydiv1').posi();
alert( MyFn('mydiv1') );
```

Just the above example is what I'm trying to realize. But I don't want to use **Object.prototype** or **jQuery**.
Below is my **wrong** approach (it is maybe helpfully what I'm trying to say or to do):

```
var MyObj = {
    method: function(args, callback) {
        if(typeof callback == "function") {
            callback();
        }
        return 123;
    }
}

MyFn = function(sId) { 
    return MyObj;
};

alert( MyFn("mydiv1").method() ); // This is ok, because it calls the method: MyObj.method() as it was expected.
alert( MyFn("mydiv1") ); // <-- But here I like to get document.getElementById("mydiv1").
```

**Note:** The **syntax** of code (how the functions are to call) is important! The functions are to call as follows: MyFn('Element-Id') or MyFn('Element-Id').posi(), but not something as follows: MyObj.MyMethode()
Do you have any idea how can I it realize? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't return 2 different results from a single function with the same input. You either return the HTMLElement object, or your own. `MyFn(id)` will always return **the same result** - regardless of what you want to do with it afterwards (such as `.method()`)

Comment: That's right! But I want to somehow achieve something as I explained above. For example jQuery do something like it. E.g. $('#Id') and $('#Id').position().left.

Comment: jQuery doesn't return an HTMLElement. It returns a jQuery wrapper object with a lot of functionality (such as `position()`). When you want the actuall element, you call `.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
var MyObj = {
    method: function(args, callback) {
        if(typeof callback == "function") {
            callback();
        }
        return 123;
    }
}

var MyFn = function(sId) { 
    this.elem = document.getElementById(sId);
    this.MyObj = MyObj;
    return this;
};

alert( MyFn("mydiv1").MyObj.method() ); 
alert( MyFn("mydiv1").elem );
```

This returns a reference to the function, after the function executes, so offers syntax much like C# extension methods for example.

Comment: Almost what I'm trying to achieve. I think with a little tricks and some functions like .apply(), .call() or .bind() it could be done. But I don't know how :)

Comment: Yeah you can use MyFunc.call(MyObj) to add the object to the function object. JavaScript is all about tricks which is why I love it :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be rather straight forward, seeing as functions are objects as well.
The way it's usually done, and the way jQuery does it, is to return a new instance of the function, which is done with a simple check

```
function MyFn(selector, context) {

    if ( !(this instanceof MyFn) ) { // not an instance

        return new MyFn(arguments);  // calls itself with the "new" keyword

    } else { // now it is an instance

        context = context || document;
        this[0] = context.getElementById(id);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Now building on that, we can add methods, but that requires prototyping them, which is the correct way to do this anyway

```
MyFn.prototype.width = function() {
    return this[0].style.width;
}
```

and even make those methods chainable

```
MyFn.prototype.width = function(width) {

    if ( width ) {
        this[0].style.width = width + 'px';
        return this;
    } else {
        return this[0].style.width;
    }

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3ba7cajL/)

Comment: 1. I can call a function like alert( element.width() );
2. I can get the id alert( element[0].id );
3. and I can get the reference as follows: alert( MyFn('mydiv1')[0] );
Very nice. But it would be even nicer if "[0]" could be eliminate. Maybe with a little tricks and some functions like .apply(), .call() it .bind() it could be done. :)

Comment: Yes, you can eliminate the `[0]` in certain instances, jQuery for instance does this for many methods, where it automatically uses the first element in the collection, and it also provides methods like `eq` to select a certain element in the collection. You could of course just replace the `[0]` with `this.elem` or something instead, if you only ever have one element, but the element has to be stored somewhere, and it can't be returned directly otherwise the methods won't be chainable, the object instance has to be returned to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, not recomended by almost all design patern, but should work :

```
MyFn = function(sId) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(param1);

    obj.method = function(args, callback) {
        if(typeof callback == "function") {
            callback();
        }
        return 123;
    }
    return MyObj;
};
```

Basicly you add the function manualy to the object.

It's not a good desing patern as someone external won't know in advance that the object has an extra method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky solution:

```
var MyObj = function (id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    // attach functions here
    obj.myFun = function () {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    return obj;
}
```

You get the object, attach your own functions to the object (hopefully without redefining existing ones), then return it.